# What does filterAcceptsRow() exactly do?

Tags: python, pyside2

there are 3 folders in one directory:

```
f:/root_folder/folder1
f:/root_folder/_folder2
f:/root_folder/folder3.asset
```

i try to customize QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow() for only show folders that with the .asset suffix.

** i know i can use QFileSystemModel.setNameFilters([*.asset]) do that. but sometimes it doesn't work.

i have Python3.7 + PySide2 5.13.0.

```py
# first inherit a QFileSystemModel instance:
listModel = QFileSystemModel()

# let the instance display only folders, except for '.' and '..':
listModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.Dirs)

# assgin a root path. i just want the model to search the 'f:/root_folder':
listModel.setRootPath("f:/root_folder")

# add a custom QSortFilterProxyModel:
myProxy = myProxyModel()
myProxy.setSourceModel(listModel)

# finally show result in a QListView:
# 'ui' is a QWidget object that contain a listView widget.
ui.listView.setModel(myProxy)
ui.listView.setRootIndex(myProxy.mapFromSource(listModel.index("f:/root_folder")))
```

here is the custom QSortFilterProxyModel:

```
# test:
class myProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        return True
```

at this point, the script works as expected: with 3 folders in the list and no filters.

if i understand correctly, the 'source_parent' should be a QModelIndex to the 'listModel', and it pointing to directory 'f:/root_folder'. and the 'source_row' should be the "ordinal number" of an item in the 'f:/root_folder', one of three folders. right?

then i added my own filters:

```py
# first try:
class myProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        source_model = self.sourceModel() 
        # 'source_model' should be the 'listModel', right?

        source_index = source_model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        # 'source_index' is a QModelIndex, pointing to 'folder1' or '_folder2' or 'folder3.asset'.

        # start filtering
        filename = source_index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        print(filename) # check
        if filename[-6:] == ".asset": return True
        else: return False
```

it should display 3 folder names on the console, display 1 folder(folder3.asset) in the list. but i got very strange result! here is the result of the console: ** it lists all my hard drives several times

```
HDD (F:)
root_folder
HDD (F:)
HDD (E:)
HDD (D:)
C:
HDD (F:)
HDD (E:)
HDD (D:)
C:
```

and the listView is empty.

is the 'source_parent' invalid? then i try this:

```py
class myProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        if not source_parent.isValid():
            print("index invalid")
            return False
        else: return True
```

got this on console:

```
index invalid
index invalid
```

and 3 folders in listView:

[image]

now i'm totally confused.

what does filterAcceptsRow() exactly do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to filter the children of the inde associated with the rootPath() of QFileSystemModel:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class SuffixDirProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._suffix = ""

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        source_model = self.sourceModel()
        if (
            self._suffix
            and isinstance(source_model, QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel)
            and source_parent == source_model.index(source_model.rootPath())
        ):
            index = source_model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
            name = index.data(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
            file_info = source_model.fileInfo(index)
            return name.split(".")[-1] == self._suffix and file_info.isDir()
        return True

    @property
    def suffix(self):
        return self._suffix

    @suffix.setter
    def suffix(self, s):
        self._suffix = s
        self.invalidateFilter()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
    model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Dirs)

    path = # "f:/root_folder"
    model.setRootPath(path)

    proxy = SuffixDirProxyModel()
    proxy.suffix = "asset"
    proxy.setSourceModel(model)

    w = QtWidgets.QListView()
    w.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
    w.setModel(proxy)
    w.setRootIndex(proxy.mapFromSource(model.index(path)))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I still don't know where I went wrong, but with working code I should be able to figure it out. thank you!

Comment: I found a issue in this code: when the setRootIndex() is first changed, this listView displays all the hard disk on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing if you don't overload it.

And you only need to overload it if the filter provided in the class you use, usually `QSortFilterProxyModel`, does not meet your needs.